# Combine two unrelated objects in table

Tags: apex, class

I have 2 object that are not related, object container contains the items(order + upc + expdate make each container unique).  Now I am creating a page that will help to find and pick these items based on SODetails.  As you see in the code there is a query inside a for loop, can anyone help me to move this query outside the loop.  I will appreciate any help.

```
Object SODetails:

Order  upc         qty1   ExpDate1    qty2  ExpDate2 
-------------------------------------------------
24432   123456789   20     1/25/2016   0      null
24432   987654321   30     2/27/2020   0      null


Object Containers:

Order    upc           ExpDate        qty-in-container  Container  Location  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
24432   123456789      1/25/2016            250         A1         L4-R8      
24432   987654321      2/27/2020            400         B4         L4-R5
```

What I have so far:

```
    SODetails=[SELECT id, Name, X1__c,  
               Account__c, 
               SKU_Type__c, UPC__c, 
               Product_Name__c, 
               Model_Number__c, 
               Comment__c, NRProducts__r.Package_Type__c, 
               NRProducts__r.Supplies__r.Size__c,
               Exp_Date_Override__c,
               Exp_Date_Override_2_lot__c,
               Exp_to_use1_1__c,
               Exp_to_use2_1__c,
               Outbound_Sales_Order__r.PO_Lookback__r.Name
               FROM SO_Detail__c
               WHERE OSO_ID__c= 'a0if00000014ECl'  
               ORDER BY UPC__c ASC];


    for(SO_Detail__c o1: SODetails){
       for(Container__c o2 : [SELECT Id, Name, ParentContainer__r.WarehouseLocation__c ,Status__c, ExpDate__c, Plate__c, Location__c, PurchaseOrderDetail__c, Qty__c, UPC__c, ParentContainer__c, Order__c  
                                  FROM Container__c 
                                  WHERE Order__c = : o1.Outbound_Sales_Order__r.PO_Lookback__r.Name
                                  AND UPC__c = : o1.UPC__c 
                                  AND ExpDate__c = : o1.Exp_Date_Override__c ])
           {
               //insert into wrapper
               MyWrapper wrappedObject = new MyWrapper(o1, o2); 
               wrappedObjects.add(wrappedObject); 

           }
        }
     }

   public List<MyWrapper> getWrappedObjects() {
        return wrappedObjects; 
    }

   public Class MyWrapper {
     public SO_Detail__c obj1 {get; set;}
     public Container__c obj2 {get; set;}

     //constructor for wrapper
     public MyWrapper (SO_Detail__c sod, Container__c cont) {
        obj1 = sod; 
        obj2 = cont; 
     }
  }
```

Comment: How do you want to combine the data in one table? Can you write the output you are after?

Comment: @Carlos.....As i understand you want combine the data based on matching field of both object ?

Comment: See [Wrapper Class](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class). You want to create a new class that combines the results of the two queries (or creates the two queries based on the input from the visualforce page & returns a single list of results).

Comment: Yes I am trying to combine this data based on matching fields (Order - UPC and ExpDate). The code above allows me to display the data in two separate tables but that is not what I want. Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: @crmprogdev, I created a wrapper class but I am having troubles placing the query outside the loop. would you please guide me on this one. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably want to create an aggregate result query, where you query Containers using what's relevant in SODetails to get the related Containers. Then, append each line of the Aggregate results with the lines from the initial SODetails query to create your new class. You can then sort the class however you want for display.